# Showing that the intersection class of A is a set (just hints, no full solutions)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is extremely basic and I understand it intuitively, but I don't know how to go about proving it.

Prove that if $A$ is a nonempty class then $\cap A$ is a set.

$\cap A$ is as a collection containing $x$ such that for all $y$ in $A$, $x \in y$.  So obviously it's a set.  How can I formally state this?

Comment: Why do you find it "obvious" that $\bigcap A$ is a set?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Fix some $y\in A$ and use the comprehension axiom. An expansion of the hint is in the spoiler-protected block.

> In more detail, show that $\bigcap A=\{x\in y:\varphi(x)\}$ for some formula $\varphi$.

Comment: @fingolfin2244: It’s a set because $y$ is a set.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, roughly, a class is a set if it is "small enough." Specifically, if $B$ is a class, and $S$ is a set such that every element of $B$ is an element of $S$, then $B$ is in fact a set. Suppose $A$ is a nonempty class; can you find a *set* which contains $\cap A$?